# hadoop how to generate inputs from map job

Tags: hadoop

I have a need where the Map job generates the set of input records which should be fed to the Map jobs (via JobTracker?).

I'm unable to think of a solution and need your help.

more details:
  I'm planning to write web crawler. The initial root level web page will be input to the mapreduce job. The Mapper/reducer will fetch web page and collect links from the page. these links should be treated as input to the mapreduce job. so I want to push these links to the jobtracker so that they can be processed as it was done for the 1st root node. There are terminal conditions which we can add (e.g. link regex matching). if regex matches then it will  not be put back to jobtracker by map (or reduce) task.

Comment: what kind of data you would like to generate like no of columns and their datatypes,your question so generic add more description.

Comment: added more details. hope that helps.

Comment: This is interesting! I do not know if it is even possible that on the run time you can increase the input. That is exactly what you want to do in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your jobs so that a mapper will take a list of URLs and run a bunch of crawlers for each URL.  So your first submissions will be a file with just a single URL.  The output of the  mapper will be a list of the links found on the pages.  The reducer will just combine the mappers outputs into a single file.

When you have this implemented you can start the next job with the output of the previous job. In the first stages you will have only mapper running because the list of your URLs will be very short,  but eventually you will be able to utilize your entire cluster.  You might experiment with changing the HDFS block size for most optimal utilization. Or you can simply treat initial under-utilization as a startup cost that will go away with as your job progresses.  Moreover if you are running on AWS it might be a good thing for you,  since you can start with very small cluster intially and purchase more machines to join your cluster as you go along.

There is a gotcha for this setup, you need to take care not to visit links you have already visited.  This might be very easy if the list of URLs is small,  but if you are trying to crawl entire internet some clever solution is in order.

Comment: thanks Vlad for your answer. I have one questions about "start the next job with the output of the previous job". does it mean that I have to batch these stages in a loop? shouldn't the reducer inform jobstracker task that it has found more job for it to dispatch to mapreduce jobs ?

Comment: I will suggest doing it in the loop.  Job tracker's job is to keep track of the running jobs.  The main reason for it the output file will not be available while your reducer job is running. The output is committed to HDFS after your reducer job finishes.  Moreover if you start launching jobs in the middle of your reduce phase and your reducer fails for some reason it will be restarted somewhere else with the same inputs. Thus causing duplicate map jobs being run. Your best bet to do it outside in the loop possibly you can leverage some existing workflow tool such as Hamake.